# test cases in inner class and outer class with junit4

Tags: java, junit4

I have 2-3 inner classes which have some test cases and those are running well(being tested). I also have some test cases in outer class but these test cases are not running. I have the following structure:

```
@org.junit.runner.RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class Outer { 
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assert("Outer" != null);
    }

    public static class Inner1 {
        @Test
        public void test2() {
            assert("Inner1" != null);
        }
    }

    public static class Inner2 {
        @Test
        public void test3() {
            assert("Inner2" != null);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, only **test2** and **test3** are being tested. **test1** is not running. I want to run all test cases. So is this possible with Junit4 or is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this problem is out of date today, since all tests run if you omit `@org.junit.runner.RunWith(Enclosed.class)` and use `junit 4.12`

Answer (score 0):

A work-around would be to put all tests from Outer into a new inner class:

```
@org.junit.runner.RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class Outer {
    public static class Inner {
        @Test
        public void test1() {
            assert ("Outer" != null);
        }
    }

    public static class Inner1 {
        @Test
        public void test2() {
            assert ("Inner1" != null);
        }
    }

    public static class Inner2 {
        @Test
        public void test3() {
            assert ("Inner2" != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this is okay. But I don't think that it's a good way. Is there not any other conventional method?